# Smarter log rotation

Tags: linux, debian, syslog, logrotate

I want to reduce the amount of logs in my system, but reduce them smartly.

The general idea is, each time you rotate, look for any warning/error/critical level logs, and keep 2 minutes of log context (before and after), regardless of its log level. The rest of logs would be simply discarded.

The current alternatives seem to be, either log *everything* and needlessly use copious amounts of disk, or just filter by specific log levels and forget any chances you had at actually trying to debug the problems.

Is there any log rotating or syslog system for Debian that can work like that?

Comment: See `man logrotate`.

Comment: Unless you are having space issues, I would am not sure I recommend "excessive" filtering of logfiles. Some times the devil is in the detail which make filtering a bad choice. Instead I would look at getting a decent log analyzer tool or writing your own log parser scripts.

Comment: maybe externalizing log to a bd and with the right tool remove what you don't want, but log should be handle with care as they can allow to recoverer from mistake or hacking

Comment: This can be accomplished by this, try looking this:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789526/log-rotating-with-a-bash-script

Comment: @SamiLaine looks like maybe I could accomplish what I want with "postrotate", I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @M_dk I generate 100MiB of logs per hour, which are very useful, but only when an error happens. Rest of the time it's space that I really cannot afford to waste.

Comment: @STenyaK: In such a situation, your approach is understandable, just wanted to be sure you were not "peeing in your pants to keep warm" ;)